# Selecting or pasting image with certain aspect ratio cause it to get out of the box

Tags: bug, design, uploader

When uploading image and selecting an image to insert (or dragging/pasing), a preview of the image is shown in the Uploader modal, before "Add picture" is clicked.

For some images, the preview breaks out of the modal's dashed box, e.g.

> [image: example of image where it gets out of preview box]

Possible fix might be changing the CSS rule on:

```
.modal.image-upload .modal-dropzone-default, .modal.image-upload .modal-dropzone-preview
```

From:

```
height: 246px;
```

To:

```
min-height: 246px;
```